# Android shows "This app won't run unless you update your google play service", but my Google play service is the latest version

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to make an app with google map API v2. When I finish my app, I run it in my cheap android Q88 tablet, which is running Android 4.1. However, it shows "This app won't run unless you update your google play service" and the "Update" button. I've tried it but Google play said that the Google play service weren't compatible with my tablet. Then I found that there was the latest version of google play service (2.0.12 (543433-10)-the latest at the time I write this post). I don't understand why my app insist on updating the google play service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the play store I have on my phone is 3.10.14, so you are behind.

Try going into app settings, and clearing the data for Google Play Store and Google Services framework. This can trigger an update check.