# Error Google Maps API v2 on real device

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to run google maps v2 api sample on a real device with Android 4.0.3 and i got the message "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services", but the Google Play Services is already updated. What may be causing this problem?

Comment: Are you using latest Google APIs as your build target?

Comment: yes, target API level 18

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102961/android-shows-this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-your-google-play-service-b

Comment: I've done this and doesn't work, but there is no Google Services framework in the app list.

Comment: Has anyone seen this problem?Any idea to solve it?